# Can someone please translate this?

Tags: translation

Just bought this painting at an estate sale today. Would like to know the translation. [image]

Answer (score 0):

"爭鳴(to contend)", 曹全堂(author name)作(write/produce)

"爭鳴" was taken out from the idiom "百家争鸣[bǎi jiā zhēng míng]" - a hundred schools of thought contend (idiom); refers to the classical philosophic schools of the Warring States period 475-221 BC.

Answer (score 0):

爭鳴 (compete to sing aloud)  is the title,

*[百鳥爭嗚](https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E7%99%BE%E9%B3%A5%E7%88%AD%E9%B3%B4/8703232) (hundreds of birds compete to sing aloud) is a metaphor for  "All different thinkings and opinions are freely expressed"*

> 百鳥爭鳴，漢語成語，拼音是bǎi niǎo zhēng míng，意思是千百種鳥一起鳴唱。出自《漢書·藝文志》。

曹全堂 (Cao Quantang) is the author

作 = by

> 爭鳴：曹全堂作 - "Contending" by Cao Quantang